# JAVA 2D-array reader using Scanner, how to convert string to objects?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am in the middle of creating a map-reader for my game. I'll explain briefly how I currently have it working and how I want it to work following that.

Atm I have two arrays. One array for Tiles (blocks that one can move on) and one for Entities (Loot, enemies, player). For Tiles I use a 2D int array, but for Entities I use an interface 2D array (that I have created). All objects in the entities implement the interface (obviously). The hard-coded Entitymap look like this:

```
    entityArray = new EntityInterface[][]{
    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Chest(7, 0, Entity.GEM, 5), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Door(1, 16, 1)},
    {player, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Loot(7, 2, Entity.GEM), null}
    };
```

The logic is already figured out,tested and that works just fine, the issue arises when I want to read these kind of Entity arrays from a text file. 
In a text file I have the following written:

```
WIDTH:7
null,null,null,null,new Door(),null,null
```

in my mapReader class I have the following code:

```
public class ReadMap
{
private int width;

public ReadMap(File mapFile) {
    readEntity(mapFile);
}

public EntityInterface[][] readEntity(File mapFile){
    EntityInterface[][] entityArray = null;
try {
    int y = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mapFile);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!line.startsWith("##")) {

        if (line.contains(":")) {
        String[] split = line.split(":");
        if (split[0].equals("WIDTH")) {
            width = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            entityArray = new EntityInterface[10][width]; //height set to 10 just for testing
        }
        }

        String[] split = line.split(",");
        if (split.length >= width) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Object object = split[i];
            System.out.println(object);
            entityArray[y][i] = object; //trying to add object to array

        }
        y++;
        }
    }

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return entityArray;
}
```

As you can see I check for the width of the array, subsequently looping through that array and then trying to add it by converting the string to an object. Of course the array will complain because the array will only take objects of type "EntityInterface" and the object is not that. I also tried casting EntityInterface to the object, basically promising the compiler that yes, the item is indeed an Entityinterface object, it didn't like that, however.

In short I want an item in the text file to be converted to an object/EntityInterface object.

What I also just tried was replacing EntityInterface with Object and then casting entityinterface further down the chain, this works for the hard-coded map (which is now a 2D object array), but not for the read map.

This is how the for-loop in the ReadMap class is now (small changes to accommodate the fact that I now use 2D-object array instead of 2D-Entityinterface array

```
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Object object = split[i];
            entityArray[y][i] = object;
        }
```

however while the converted string into object is an object on paper, it's not like the objects I have in my hard-coded maps, unfortunately. It still throws CastClassException, cannot convert string to entityinterface. NOTE: The hard-coded object 2D array works and I do cast entityinterface to that list, which works flawlessly, it's just that with the text-file the issues arise.

This is the error the compile throws at me
[ERROR]java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to XXX.EntityInterface[/ERROR]

EDIT: I solved this by converting strings into code with a switch case i.e if it sees ("DOOR") it'll fetch the args for that door and then create a new door with the args provided

Comment: You're trying to cast `String` to `EntityInterface` while both entities has no relationship with each other. You have to construct an object that implements `EntityInterface` (if that's an interface as the name says) by a using a constructor.

Comment: Create a factory that will create the right EntityInterface object when passed a String as parameter (e.g. when param="Door" return new Door(...))

Comment: All objects implement EntityInterface. The issue occurs when I try to fetch the data from a text file (which returns all data as a String) I want to convert this string, I tried converting it to an object which worked, but casting EntityInterface on that object doesn't work, because it still sees it as a string

Comment: I see what you mean @StephaneM , but that would entail issues for the specific parameters that Door contains, I rather stupidly left out the args for the Door object in the text file, my apologies on that one. So in reality the door would have properties like new Door(x,y, LinkedMapFile) these are specific for each and every Door, same goes for loot and other items.

Comment: @Hoaz ... did you have read what I said. The `String` object that you have retrieved from a text file is **not** implementing `EntityInterface`. You can upcast the `String` to `Object` and see it as `Object`, but it stays as a `String` there ... You cannot expect the program to magically convert it to `EntityInterface`. You have to provide a  tool to convert a `String` to `EntityInterface`, and that's by constructing it yourself.

Comment: @KarelG I'll look into

Comment: @KarelG I have come so way of implementing the decoding system, however, another issue - and this is an odd one, it shouldn't be a problem but is - 
`   
     private List<String> retrieveArgs(String string){
 System.out.println(string);
 List<String> argArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] args = string.split(" ");

 for (String arg : args) {
     String[] argument = arg.split("=");
     if(argument[0] != "(")
     {
      argArray.add(argument[1]);
     }
 }
 return argArray;
    }
` The input for this is ( x=5 y=6 z=7 )   I try to exclude (, but it still reads (!

Comment: Edit your initial post, code in comments is unreadable.